# Which commands and functions are not supported in TCL based on the version

Tags: version-control, tcl, version, tk-toolkit

SO far I've been using TCL 8.6 , but recently I had to move back to 8.0 because the program I am using only supports 8.0

The issue is that I can't find a documentation or a comparison between what new commands and functions are compatible and what are not

Are there any websites that contain such info

//please note that I checked the tcl.tk website and it only features what is new  per version but not so specific

Comment: I feel your pain. From 2005 to 2012 I used a database with embedded tcl 8.0p2. Make sure you bookmark http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.0/TclCmd/contents.htm

Answer (score 2):

[This page](http://wiki.tcl-lang.org/405), and the pages it links to, have fairly detailed information on command and syntax changes. You may have to search backwards to find the first version that supports the feature you're wondering about.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.tcl.tk/man/ has links to documentation for Tcl commands in various versions from 7.5 to 8.6, though it skips 8.1 for some reason.

Comment: It's _really_ not recommended to use 8.1 in production; it had some major faults that weren't really worked out until 8.2. There weren't that many actual command changes from 8.0, but the way many things worked changed a lot (as that was when Tcl gained unicode support).

Answer (score 2):

Only supporting 8.0? That's rather old. (I've still got some systems like that, but they're really just on life support.)

The second-most definitive source of what has changed between versions is the `changes` file in any Tcl source code distribution. (The first most accurate source is comparing the source code, but that's a bit annoying prior to 8.1 for various unimportant reasons.) You can use the [current version](http://core.tcl-lang.org/tcl/tree?ci=tip) for this, since those old parts of that file are effectively static; [here's](http://core.tcl-lang.org/tk/tree?ci=tip) the equivalent for Tk. The file includes a *lot* more information than you probably need, including mentioning many of the more significant bugfixes as well as some cases where functionality flapped a bit during betas (we try to avoid doing that, but it happens occasionally).

However, the big things that far back are fairly simple, so we can probably narrow the things to watch out for to these big-ticket items:

- Expansion syntax (`{*}...`) was introduced in Tcl 8.5. Before that, you use `eval` a *lot* more.
- There's a large bunch of commands in modern Tcl that simply weren't there back then. There are workarounds for *some* of these; easier to just try and see what's actually missing that you expect and then ask here again than to try to anticipate them all. Some known exceptions that are known to be *entirely* unavailable for 8.0:

  - dictionaries
  - ensembles
  - coroutines
  - the TclOO object system
  - the Ttk widget set
- Tcl 8.0 assumed that characters were always 8-bit quantities and made no attempt to understand encodings. It just slings bytes around. (This also means that the `encoding` command was absent, and so too was the `-encoding` option to `fconfigure`.)

  - Make sure you only use ASCII in your scripts themselves. Saves pain.
- The RE engine in 8.0 was different to the one used from 8.1 onwards. It's much simpler, and supports only a fraction of what the newer engine does.
- Threading support in 8.0 and before is not for the faint of heart. *Assume your code is single-threaded* and avoid a lot of difficult debugging.